# Ending the tag challenge

Tags: discussion, tags, site-promotion

I think the time has come to give up on the tag challenge efforts. The last two challenges ([June 10-23](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2043/33442) and [June 24-July 7](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2074/33442)) have collectively garnered only two entries and very little tagging effort.

Unless someone has a brilliant idea to save it I think we should give it a break for a while. Perhaps after some rest (a few months or a year) we could have anything contest to push us over the line to the generalist badge which we are now much closer to.

Comment: The earlier one shows improvement on all tags, and potentially the desired halo effect where *they continued to grow afterwards* (check the numbers). so that's a big **YAY!** Last one was a dud, ok, but it was a holiday week/end in the US.... I've been checking since Monday for some new tags, lol. If you want to do something else, it's cool. Is it such a hardship? Can you share the burden? Is there a way to boost it? or is it about seeing *faster* results towards this ephemeral "graduation" moving goalpost out of our control that will bring the joys of an Earthly Paradise? … What's the goal?

Comment: @wetcircuit you are welcome to take it over it you want. But honestly most of the activity in the previous one was my own retagging efforts. And it's not much of a tag challenge if it's really just logging stuff I would do anyway. Ideally I'd love to keep it going but I don't see the point if we don't get more entries. Perhaps I'm not good at picking tags?

Answer (score 9):

I for one just want to thank you and those involved in the effort. It is hard to measure the effects of these things but they absolutely are a positive for this community.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're right that there's burnout and it's time to take a break.  Especially given that it's summer for most of the world's population.

Let's officially end the challenge and restart it at a later date.  And those of us who wish can stay mindful of retagging and working towards Generalist.

Answer (score 4):

As the one who proposed the extended challenge, I agree -- it needs a break, at the very least.